# Why does ['access' !~ 'no'] filter out ways with access = unknown in Overpass?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

If I use this query in Overpass

```
[out:json];
area[name="Squirrel Hill"];
way(area)
  ['access' !~ 'no'];
out;
```

then [this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/11947323) (OSM ID 11947323) is not in the result set.
However, if this is my query:

```
[out:json];
area[name="Squirrel Hill"];
way(area);
out;
```

The way shows up as expected in the output.

Here you can see that the previously mentioned way does not have the access=no tag.
[image: screenshot showing that Consentino Drive does not have the access = no tag, only the access = unknown tag]

What is causing this? Is the `unknown` tag somehow a subset of the `no` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter `['access' !~ 'no'];` checks that the tag value for the key `access` does not match the regular expression `"no"`.

As the string "unk**no**wn" contains `"no"` somewhere in the middle, your way is being filtered out.

Note that regular expressions match anywhere inside a string, unless you explicitly use `"^no$"` to mark the start and end of a string.